# How to avoid cropping about depth frame in ARCore when acquire depth image?

Tags: android, arcore, depth

I am going to get depth image when playback with mp4 file in ARCore.
First, I recorded live camera frames(depth, color) to mp4 file.
this mp4 file has 3 tracks(1280*720(color), 640*480(color), 640*480(depth)).
Next, I start playback this mp4 file using session.setPlaybackDataSet() function in ARCore.
and I tried to get color image depth image using below functions.

textureImage = frame.acquireCameraImage();
depthImage = frame.acquireDepthImage();

In this case, textureImage's size is 640*480, but depthImage's size is 640*360(cropped).
But I want to get 640*480 depthImage(non-cropped).
I tried to search functions for changing frame's size before start playback.
But I cannot find any solution.
How can I get non-cropped depth image. My tested device is Samsung Galaxy S20+.
Please help me.